# Parallelization of a for loop in Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have a long doubly-nested for loop to go over for many trials. I want to do this in parallel because these trials are independent of one another. How do I implement this efficiently in Java similar to OpenMP in C++? I would be running this on a node with 64 processors, so I want each core to do one measure.

Relevant code:

```
//I want each measure to perform the doubly nested loop at the same time.

for (int i : measures) {

  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
    array[i*N*N + j*N + k] = someFunc(i,j,k);
    }
  }

}
```

Edit: Still having issues:

```
//sim is a 1D array of type double
//gM is an array of type SMconf
//gene[foo].annot is a LinkedHashSet of URIs.
//Javadoc http://www.semantic-measures-library.org/sml/docs/apidocs/

Arrays.parallelSetAll( sim, i -> {
    try {
        engine.compare( gM[i/(N*N)], gene[(i/N)%N].annot, gene[i % N].annot );
    }
    catch (SLIB_Ex_Critic ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Exp2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
});
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Learn about threads: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: You could try to use [parallel streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#executing_streams_in_parallel) - though you might need to change `someFunc` signature to accept directly the array item instead of its position in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int N=5;
    int array[]=new int[200];
    int [] measures={1,2,3,4,5};

    Arrays.stream(measures).parallel().forEach(i->{
        IntStream.range(0, N).parallel().forEach(j->{
            IntStream.range(0, N).parallel().forEach(k->{
                array[i*N*N+j*N + k]= someFunc(i,j,k);
            });
        });
    });


    Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Considering `measures` is an array and not an `ArrayList`. You may want to put locks while writing to `array[]`.
I hope you are not using `array` as a variable name.

Comment: What if measures is not an array of int, but an array of objects of class Measure?

Comment: if `measures` is not int, how is your code `for (int i : measures)` running? Also why are you skipping index while setting `array[i*N*N+j*N + k]`?

Comment: Sorry, where am i skipping index?

Comment: in `array[i*N*N+j*N + k]` you are multiplying with `N` and adding `k` and `j` so you are bound to skip elements

Answer (score 0):

Probably it would be moreless efficient to use Java-8 method [`Arrays.parallelSetAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSetAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-):

```
Arrays.parallelSetAll(array, idx -> someFunc(idx/(N*N), (idx/N)%N, idx % N));
```

This sets the array elements independently in parallel. While you may have an overhead for division, it's probably much less than overhead for creating nested parallel streams as in @pallavt answer. Though it may depend on problem size.

If your `someFunc` throws checked exception, rethrow it as unchecked one:

```
Arrays.parallelSetAll(array, idx -> {
    try {
        return someFunc(idx/(N*N), (idx/N)%N, idx % N);
    }
    catch(MyCheckedException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
});
```

Comment: What if the generator function throws an exception. It's happening to me and the try catch that Netbeans makes by default is not working within the parallelSetall function.

Comment: @henri, edited the answer to show how to handle checked exception. In general in Java-8 you should prefer unchecked exceptions everywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much Tagir. I tried again, but it says "bad return type in lamdba expression missing return value."

Comment: It should return a double.

Comment: @henri, you're missing the `return` statement in `try` block which is present in my code. Look carefully.

Comment: Thank you Tagir. I added the return, but I'm getting the same error. :/